# After Adding a New Router I can access my website via the IP address but not the website

Tags: router, internet, webserver

When I go to 192.168.1.50 I can access the website but when I go to advsystems.com I cannot. I was able to access the website before I changed routers.

Comment: Please search this website for "NAT loopback" or "hairpin NAT".

Comment: I can see it internally but I want it from internet

Comment: Try checking the port forwarding on the router.